# Find the smallest integer value of $n$ such that $f(x) =\lceil x\rceil=O(x^n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My $f(x)$ in this question is ceiling function of $x$, $\lceil x\rceil$

I'm not too sure how to work with the ceiling function and don't even know where to start with this one.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$${x\le \text{ceil}(x)\le x+1
\\\implies
\\1\le {\text{ceil}(x)\over x}\le 1+{1\over x}
\\,
\\x>0
}
$$

Comment: so ceil(x) <= x+1   which  turns to  x+1 <= x+x  , x > 1 . so therefore x+1 <= 2|x| , x > 1.   so   f(x) is O(x) for c = 2 and k  = 1 ?

Comment: Of course the bounds are tight but also could be interpreted as yours.